# How can I use UniswapV2 to create my own LP tokens?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, liquidity-provider

I'm new to DeFi and liquidity farming. I'm just trying to build a simple LP farming application for testing and I'm trying to generate some of my own LP tokens to be used as my reward tokens.

I'd like to know if there is any example that people have worked on - using Uniswap smart contracts like UniswapV2Factory and UniswapV2Router, to create their own LP tokens? I'm currently using ERC20 tokens that I defined myself.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

uniswap has its own erc20 token if you have seen [link here](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2ERC20.sol) of UniswapV2ERC20.sol
you just need to replace it with you token but you it must needed the same functionality to work with uniswapV2.

**edited
you can change name and symbol to make it different...
**